# c++ how can I ignore the second message in this condition

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
double const A = 0.80,
             B = 0.60,
             C = 0.40,
             D = 0.20;
char code1,
     code2;

int volume,
    student;

double price,
       totalcost,
       totalvolume,
       totalprofit;

cout << "Enter the number price for one book :";
cin >> price;
cout << "Enter the book in stock :";
cin >> volume;
cout << "Enter the number of student :";
cin >> student;
cout << "Is the book required or suggested? Enter 'R' or 'S' :";
cin >> code1;
cout << "Is the book new or used? Enter 'N' or 'U' :";
cin >> code2;

if (code1 == 'R' && code2 == 'N')
    {
    totalvolume = student * A - volume;
    cout << " We need to buy :" << totalvolume << endl;
    if (totalvolume !=0)
        totalcost = totalvolume * price;
    cout << " totalcost is :" << totalcost << endl;
    }
else
    {

    }
cout << " We need to buy :" << totalvolume << endl;


return 0;
}
```

I wonder if anyone can help me with this, is there a way I can ignore the second output message("totalcost is") and only print out the("We need to buy") when the totalvolume is 0? This is my first project in college, while loop haven't been taught yet and not allowed to use. I can only use if statement or switch. Thank you.

Comment: Paste your code [here](http://format.krzaq.cc/) and click "Format". You'll see the problem.

Comment: The `cout` for `totalcost is` needs to be moved inside the `if` block above it.  Add `{}` to that block: `if (totalvolume !=0) { totalcost = totalvolume * price; cout << " totalcost is :" << totalcost << endl; }` Also, the last `cout` for `We need to buy` probably needs to be omitted completely since `totalvolume` is uninitialized in that case.

Comment: Thank you for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet of code:

```
if (totalvolume !=0)
        totalcost = totalvolume * price;
    cout << " totalcost is :" << totalcost << endl;
```

The third line in this code snippet "totalcost is: " will always print if the outer "if" statement condition is satisfied. If you want it to print only when this if statement is true, you have to enclose it in curly braces {}. So it should look like this:

```
if (totalvolume !=0){
        totalcost = totalvolume * price;
        cout << " totalcost is :" << totalcost << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help